# Gtk MenuBar kills MenuItems after the pointer hovers over them

Tags: python, user-interface, pygtk

I have a plain `gtk.MenuBar` frame below. Whenever the mouse hovers over an item, and that submenu is hidden due to lost focus, upon revisiting that submenu, all items are lost.

The expected behavior is that the menu items re-appear in the order they were added to their menus and submenus each time 'File', 'Game' and 'Help' are activated with the pointer.

What is the cause of this perceived bug? Does the `gtk.MenuBar` require more "implementing" to function properly?

The undesired result is illustrated below:

[image: pre-hover]
[image: post-hover]

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import gtk

def callbackz(*argv):
    print str(*argv)

class ChessMenuBar(gtk.MenuBar):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChessMenuBar, self).__init__()

        menu_file = gtk.Menu()

        item_open = gtk.MenuItem('Open')
        item_save = gtk.MenuItem('Save')
        item_quit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        menu_file.append(item_open)
        menu_file.append(item_save)
        menu_file.append(item_quit)

        menu_game = gtk.Menu()
        item_newg = gtk.MenuItem('Star New Game')
        menu_game.append(item_newg)

        menu_help = gtk.Menu()
        item_help = gtk.MenuItem('Help')
        menu_help.append(item_help)

        # --  main categories
        item_file = gtk.MenuItem('File')
        item_game = gtk.MenuItem('Game')
        item_help = gtk.MenuItem('Help')

        item_file.set_submenu(menu_file)
        item_game.set_submenu(menu_game)
        item_help.set_submenu(menu_help)

        self.append(item_file)
        self.append(item_game)
        self.append(item_help)


        for _ in [ item_file, item_game, item_help,
                item_help, item_newg, item_open, 
                item_quit, item_save]:
            _.connect('activate', callbackz)

class PyApp(gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(PyApp, self).__init__()

        self.set_title("Simple menu")
        self.set_size_request(250, 200)
        self.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.Color(6400, 6400, 6440))
        self.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)

        mb = ChessMenuBar()

        vbox = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
        vbox.pack_start(mb, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)

        self.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
        self.show_all()


PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

---

```
$ winPython --version
Python 2.7.3

$ cat /cygdrive/c/Python27/Lib/site-packages/gtk-2.0/pygtk-2.22.0-py2.7.egg-info
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: pygtk
Version: 2.22.0
( abbreviated )
Platform: MS Windows
Requires: pycairo (>=1.0.2)
Requires: pygobject (>=2.21.3)
Provides: p
Provides: y
Provides: g
Provides: t
Provides: k
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is likely due to having several pygtk all-in-one bundles installed simultaneously.

e.g

```
pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.2.win32-py2.7.msi
(and)
pygtk-all-in-one-2.22.6.win32-py2.7.msi
```

To fix the issue, uninstall all versions using the installer or the control panel and install only one.

Answer (score 0):

Does it help if you store the menu items somewhere, e.g. in `self`, by replacing

```
item_open = gtk.MenuItem('Open')
```

with

```
self.item_open = gtk.MenuItem('Open')
```

(and similarly for the other menu items)?

I don't know PyGTK that well, but I suspect that it creates Python objects that correspond to GTK menu-item objects/structures.   These Python objects might be getting garbage collected at the end of the constructor, and when they get garbage collected, they might delete the underlying GTK C/C++ object.  My suspicions are that the menu items are disappearing because they are getting deleted.

By storing the Python objects, you're preventing them from being garbage collected, which should prevent the corresponding C/C++ objects from being deleted.

This is speculation, however; I haven't tested your code to verify that this suggestion works, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but the results are the same even if pointers to the item and menu objects are retained as attributes on `self`.